# Linking personal microsoft accounts with oauth 2

Tags: node.js, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on an Alexa app, and wish to integrate with [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onenote). So far I've set up my an app in AWS Lambda, Microsoft application registration portal, and the Alexa development portal.

In Microsoft application registration portal I have

- the MS Application ID
- the MS password/public key
- Web Platform with Implicit flow
- redirect URLs of:

`https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/APP_ID
https://layla.amazon.com/api/skill/link/APP_ID
https://amazon.com`

- Delegated permissions of:

`Notes.Read.All
User.Read`

in AWS Lambda config i have:

- an env variable of `APPLICATION_ID = amzn1.ask.skill.SKILL_ID`

This env variable might be the issue, I'm a little unsure.

in Alexa Skills I have

- Account Linking set to Yes
- Authorization URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- Client Id linking back to my MS Application ID
- A domain list of Microsoft login domains

[image: Microsoft domain list]

- scope's of:

`offline_access
user.read
notes.read.all`

- Auth Garant Type set to Auth code grant
- Access token URI = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
- client secret from MS Application
- credentials in request body

When I go to my development skill in the Alexa app and try to link my Microsoft account, I get "Microsoft Account unavailable".  The account I am using is a standard Microsoft outlook.com account and not a work or school account.

I'm wondering if maybe the Application ID I have in my AWS Lambda config is wrong.  It is being used in this bit of code:

```
  var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
  exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Verify that the Request is Intended for Your Service
    // This value is set on the server or in the .env file
    // SETUP NOTE: Add Lambda Environment Variable called APPLICATION_ID
    var appId = process.env.APPLICATION_ID;

    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = appId;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  }
```

Comment: So this might be because of my use of `Notes.Read.All` going to test tonight.  From reading the permissions documentation, that one is only for school and work accounts.

Comment: Nope that wasn't it.